# PostSharp 1.5 licencing

Tags: licensing, postsharp

We are evaluating PostSharp for logging purposes to use in a our project (implemented in .Net). Currently it is running in production enviroment. Can mixing with PostSharp raise licencing issues? As far as I know it is partially free. Am I wrong? What future licencing problems (i.e. is PostSharp planning to be non-free for future releases) can we face, if there are any?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. See [[here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846)] for details, and the [[help/on-topic]] for more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [**PostSharp licensing FAQ**](http://www.postsharp.org/about/license) explains this in great detail.

> Can mixing with PostSharp raise licencing issues?

You're unlikely to have future problems if you don't link to the part that actually does the transformations (that's PostSharp.Core). PostSharp.Laos and PostSharp.Public are what most applications will typically link to.

> As far as I know it is partially free. Am I wrong?

It's all free as in beer, unless you (1) link to Core and (2) need to distribute your app outside your company. In that case, you have to buy a license. Core is released under GPL.

Answer (score 0):

See the [licensing options](http://www.postsharp.org/about/license), which neatly summarizes answers to both those questions at the top of the page.